# Modify parent class variables inside thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to create an Android app in Java (using Ubuntu 11.10 with the latest Eclipse, ADT and latest Android SDK).

I have the below thread inside a function of its parent class:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                    try{
                        list_items = rtm_instance.update_notes_list(list_items);
                        list_items.add("test");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
}).start();
```

`list_items` and `rtm_instance` are member variables of the class inside which the thread is written. It seems that `list_items` inside the thread is a snapshot of `list_items` in the parent class at the point of `start()`ing the thread.

Though `rtm_instance.update_notes_list` returns an updated notes list as expected, the changes made to `list_items` don't seem to modify the same variable in the parent class. Modifying `list_items` does nothing more than modify the said variable's copy **inside** the thread.

I want the modification to take place in the parent (UI) thread as well, so that an Android `ListAdapter` detects those and modifies the corresponding `ListView`. How do I modify the parent thread variable `list_items` from the child thread posted above?

Thanks!

Comment: Volatile variable is like something which is referred every time by the thread.. So if u make list_items volatile then it ll updated

Comment: @devA That didn't help, using `runOnUiThread` worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the update to happen on the UI thread. You should post a runnable to the Handler from the UIThread. Alternatively you could call runOnUiThread. To have the list on the parent you could define a method on the parent called updateList(String val) and call this rather than changing the list directly.

Comment: Yeah, I want the update to happen on the UI thread. Sorry if it was confusing. Edited the question.

Comment: I used `runOnUiThread` and it worked. Thanks for helping me in this!